# How to separate this Python comma separated string list in to multiple key value pairs?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, matrix-multiplication

If I have the input of the form 
(`(0, 1), A 0 0.0), ((0, 2), A 0 0.0), ((0, 0), A 0 0.0)` where `(0,1) , (0,2), (0,0)` are the keys, how do I separate them into multiple key value pairs.

for example if I want to print key, values the above should return:

```
(0,1) , A 0 0 0.0
(0,2) , A 0 0 0.0
(0,0) , A 0 0 0.0
```

This output will be used in my Reducer function for which the code is:

```
import sys
import string
import numpy
import re


#number of columns of A/rows of B
n = int(sys.argv[1])

#Create data structures to hold the current row/column values (if needed; your code goes here)

currentkey = None
# input comes from STDIN (stream data that goes to the program)
for line in sys.stdin:
    #print(line)
    #Remove leading and trailing whitespace
    #line = line.strip().replace("(","").replace(")","")
    #re.sub(r"[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", line)
    #line = line.strip().translate(None, "()")
    line = line.strip()


    #''.join(line.translate(string.maketrans("()[]"," "*4)).split(' ')[::2])
    print(line)

    #print(line.__class__)


    #Get key/value
    key, value = line.split('\t',1)




    print ("key: " + str(key))
    print ("Value: " + str(value))
    #Parse key/value input (your code goes here)
    # for val in value:
    #   if val[0] == "A":
    #       list_a.append(val)
    #       print(list_a)
    #
    #
    #   else:
    #       list_b.append(val)
    #       print(list_b)






    #If we are still on the same key...
    if key==currentkey:

        #Process key/value pair (your code goes here)
        for a in list_a:
            #remove first two elems so that we're left with value
            a = a[2:]
        print(list_a)
        result_a = list(map(int,result_a))
        for b in list_b:
            b = b[2:]
        print(list_b)
        result_b = list(map(int, result_b))
        #multiply result_a and result_b for current key
        result_ab = [a*b for a,b in zip(result_a,result_b)]
        finalResult = sum(result_ab)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you would extract values from your tuple

`((0, 1), A 0 0.0)` is one tuple, and you can access values in tuple by `tuple[0]`, `tuple[1]` and so on... see [more examples here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm)

here `line[0]` (`(0,1)`) is another tuple so we will need to convert that to `str` in order to output final result

`finalData = dataRDD.map(lambda line : str(line[0]) + "," + line[1])`

---

***Test:***

```
>>> data = [((0, 1), 'A 0 0.0'), ((0, 2), 'A 0 0.0'), ((0, 0), 'A 0 0.0')]
>>> dataRDD = sc.parallelize(data)
>>> for i in dataRDD.collect():
...     print(i)
... 
((0, 1), 'A 0 0.0')
((0, 2), 'A 0 0.0')
((0, 0), 'A 0 0.0')
>>> finalData = dataRDD.map(lambda line : str(line[0]) + "," + line[1])
>>> for i in finalData.collect():
...     print(i)
... 
(0, 1),A 0 0.0
(0, 2),A 0 0.0
(0, 0),A 0 0.0
>>> finalData.saveAsTextFile('/user/cloudera/test123')
----------
$ hadoop fs -cat /user/cloudera/test123/*
(0, 1),A 0 0.0
(0, 2),A 0 0.0
(0, 0),A 0 0.0
```

Comment: This won't work as I'm not using PySpark. What I want to do is naive multiplication using MapReduce. My Mapper function returns the input in the form ((0, 1), A 0 0.0), ((0, 2), A 0 0.0), ((0, 0), A 0 0.0). I'm having trouble writing my Reducer function. I have included the code in edits to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this we can use simple python unpacking.

```
tup = ((0, 1), 'A 0 0.0'), ((0, 2), 'A 0 0.0'), ((0, 0), 'A 0 0.0')
A = []
B = []
for each in tup:
    (x,y),z = each
    A.append((x,y))
    B.append(z)
```